# Unable to login after upgrading to SugarCRM ver 8.0.0 Pro

Tags: upgrade, sugarcrm, password-encryption, password-hash

I have updated a SugarCRM instance from 6.5.14 PRO to 8.0.0 PRO using silent upgrades. Every thing works fine and instace gets updated to ver 8.0.0 successfully. But after upgrade i have a strange issue of getting logedin into the Sugar 8.0.0 using my administrator account.

When i try to get log in Sugar gives me a message of Invalid Credntials.

[image: enter image descr## Heading ##iption here]

In sugarcrm.log Sugar also only writes that the user login attempt failed for user  and in php log there is no message regarding any type of failure.

I have also tried to add these parameters in config_override file but it dosen't work in either way:

```
$sugar_config['passwordHash']['allowLegacy'] = true;
$sugar_config['passwordHash']['rehash'] = false;
```

If i replace the password of my administrator account in users table with the password of administrator account available in the users table of a standard 8.0.0 instance then SugarCRM let me logged in in my upgraded instance.

**NOTE**: An important point to indicate here is that the problem exists only for the users having their passwords saved in MD5 format in table users and not for the users which already have their passwords converted in SHA format.

Any idea how to update the passwords or add any parameters in config to solve this login failure problem in my upgraded instance.

Comment: Do the hashes look different in format than the standard one? If so then maybe an upgrade script failed? Check the scripts in the upgrade zip, there might be one for upgrading passwords.

Comment: Is it possible that there are spaces in the passwords? What response do you get when you browse the requests to the token endpoint?

Comment: @Jay I have checked the upgrade scripts but not found any script realted to upgrading passwords.

Comment: @Reisclef I have rechedcked my password and not found any spaces int it.

Comment: @RahatAli I don't know if spaces are a problem. However in pre-Sugar8, there was accidental html encoding going on, leading to problems with characters like the quote `"` and probably also `<` and `>`. I doubt that is the cause of your issues though. I haven't check the upgrade scripts myself, but I will try to have a look at those of 6.5 -> 7 when I get a chance. Also I will check if working upgraded instances have old working PWs in old or new format.

Comment: Oh btw, what version of php is this about? You do have php-hash installed, right?

Comment: @Jay I am using this version of PHP 7.1.18-1+ubuntu16.04.1